# Find all views of a particular type presently displayed in BackboneJS or BackboneLayout

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-layout-manager

This project uses [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) with [BackboneLayout](http://layoutmanager.org/).

There is a rather complex hierarchy of views - four to five levels deep in some cases.

I have a situation where I would like one view to trigger a change in another view, but listeners are not an option. (results in too many listeners, kills memory).

```
Top -> X -> Y
Top -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

`Top` is the top level view, which has one `X` view , which has multiple `Y` views.
`Top` view also contains one `B` view, which contain multiple `B` views, each of which contain multiple `C` views, each of which contain multiple `D` views, each of which contain multiple `E` views.

A change in a `Y` view needs to affect all `E` views that are presently rendered. This would be perfect for listeners, if not for the problem mentioned earlier. Thus I am looking for an alternative way to accomplish the same thing.

I am thinking of getting the `Top` view to find all of its children that are of type `E`, or something along those lines. Other solutions are welcome too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I'd have `Top` maintain a list of all `E` instances - this would just be something in application code, might be in `E.initialize()`, or via your own methods for adding/removing nodes in your view heirarchy, if you have them -  and it's *own* event handler that listens for `change` events on all Ys, and re-renders the `E`s. If it's prohibitively expensive to listen to `Y` changes, trigger a custom `Y-change` (or whatever) event on your `Top` from your application code in `Y`, and have Top listen to that event instead.

It's very easy to have the list of E instances get out of sync, but, well, that's why listeners exist. Tread carefully and make sure Top has hooks into every point down the `B->C->D->E` tree and knows what changes to make to it's (essentially denormalized) list of `E`'s when there is a change.